# Add a conditional formula column

Tags: r

I have a data frame with `propertyID` and `fromLocalTime` columns. In R, I want to create column `followup` that does this logic in every row:

If propertyID row `#235364=propertyID row #235363`, return fromLocalTime `(row #235364 - fromLocalTime row #235363)`, otherwise return 0.

(Note the format of the followup column will be in numeric days)

example data outputs

```
> dput(head(df))
structure(list(propertyID = c(924561.18, 924561.18, 924561.18, 
924601.14, 924601.14, 924647.76), fromLocalTime = structure(c(1570808280, 
1571231640, 1571246760, 1570799580, 1571231400, 1571160060), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = ""), followup = c(NA, 4.9, 0.175, NA, 
0.208246527777778, NA)), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), groups = structure(list(
    propertyID = c(924561.18, 924601.14, 924647.76), .rows = list(
        1:3, 4:5, 6L)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE))

> data.frame(df)
   propertyID       fromLocalTime       followup
1    924561.2 2019-10-11 11:38:00             NA
2    924561.2 2019-10-16 09:14:00      4.9000000
3    924561.2 2019-10-16 13:26:00      0.1750000
4    924601.1 2019-10-11 09:13:00             NA
5    924601.1 2019-10-16 09:10:00      0.2082465
6    924647.8 2019-10-15 13:21:00             NA
7    924654.4 2019-10-15 09:08:00             NA
8    924677.7 2019-09-20 14:25:00             NA
9    924677.7 2019-09-23 11:40:00      0.1202257
10   924724.3 2019-10-17 13:10:00             NA
11   925936.5 2019-10-15 12:06:00             NA
12   925936.5 2019-10-16 08:03:00      0.8312500
13   925939.8 2019-10-15 11:11:00             NA
14   926529.2 2019-10-17 11:04:00             NA
```

Therefore, my expected output is:

```
> data.frame(df)
   propertyID       fromLocalTime       followup
1    924561.2 2019-10-11 11:38:00             NA
2    924561.2 2019-10-16 09:14:00      4.9000000
3    924561.2 2019-10-16 13:26:00      0.1750000
4    924601.1 2019-10-11 09:13:00             NA
5    924601.1 2019-10-16 09:10:00      4.997917
6    924647.8 2019-10-15 13:21:00             NA
7    924654.4 2019-10-15 09:08:00             NA
8    924677.7 2019-09-20 14:25:00             NA
9    924677.7 2019-09-23 11:40:00      2.885417
10   924724.3 2019-10-17 13:10:00             NA
11   925936.5 2019-10-15 12:06:00             NA
12   925936.5 2019-10-16 08:03:00      0.8312500
13   925939.8 2019-10-15 11:11:00             NA
14   926529.2 2019-10-17 11:04:00             NA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
 mutate(new = ifelse(propertyID == lag(propertyID), (fromLocalTime - lag(fromLocalTime))/24, 0))
```

Comment: it works for most of my data! I will edit the post to share a little more of my data to show the cases it doesn't work

Comment: Some of the calculations are correct and some aren't. I'm not sure why?

Comment: Me neither. I get the exact same values as your expected ones...